# IE11 Edge mode - Sarissa.js

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, sarissa

My website is old, and now need to upgrade to support IE11 Edge mode.
It works fine in the IE compatibility mode but get an error in edge mode.

```
var xmlDoc = Sarissa.getDomDocument();
xmlDoc.async = false;
xmlDoc.load("....");
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'load'
```

My Sarissa version is 0.9, I have tried to upgraded to 0.9.9.6, but got same error.

If the sarissa.js is not support IE11, what framework I can use to replace it?
Or there are any solution to update the sarissa.js to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an outstanding bug [where IE11 is not supported by Sarissa](http://sourceforge.net/p/sarissa/bugs/63/), which whilst not fixed in a released version, [appears to be resolved in the CVS version](http://sarissa.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sarissa/sarissa/src/main/js/gr/abiss/js/sarissa/sarissa.js?revision=1.35&view=markup)